# Convert specific datetime with specific timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i convert this datetime format:

```
2013-05-04 17:25:00
```

To a timezone that i can specify. Something like this:

```
convertTimeZone('2013-05-04 17:25:00', '+3');
```

And return the following datetime with the specified timezone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this is enough to get you started

```
// time should be a string in your format
// offset should be an int (i.e. 3 or -3)
function convertTimeZone(time, offset) {
    time = time.replace('-','/');
    return new Date(time).addHours(parseInt(offset, 10));
}
```

To be called as such

```
convertTimeZone('2013-05-04 17:25:00', 3);
convertTimeZone('2013-05-04 17:25:00', -3);
```

Javascript doesn't like `-` so replace them with `/` which it will accept.  None of this uses jquery, this is just basic javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com/)

then you could do something like this (just an example may not match exactly what you are asking)

```
var date1 = moment.utc("2013-05-04 17:25:00").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");

console.log(date1.toString());

var date2 = moment.utc(date1).add("hours", 3).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");

console.log(date2.toString());
```

which will output

```
2013-05-04T17:25:00
2013-05-04T20:25:00
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/cjFSH/)